# Kubernetes Storage

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

We have Azure Kubernetes Cluster, 2 Nodes, and 30 GB Os Disk.

We are deploying multiple application on the Cluster with 2 replicas and 2 pods per application. Now we are facing issue with the disk space. The 30GB Os disk is full and we have to change the 30GB to 60GB.

I tried to increase the disk size to 60GB but It will destroy the whole cluster and recreating it. So we loose all the deployments and we have to deploy all the applications again.

How can I overcome with the disk space issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to overcome this really.

Recreate the cluster with something like 100GB os disk (maybe use ephemeral os disks to cut costs). Alternatively - create a new system node pool, migrate resources to it and decommission the old one.